# Handling numbers as text in sumifs formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sumifs formula with a filter range on a column with a year.  Sometime this year is formatted as a number, other times it is formatted as text.

How can I make my sumifs formula flexible enough to handle both years formatted as numbers and as text?

For example, this formula returns incorrect results when passed a year formatted as text:
`=SUMIFS(C3:C6,B3:B6,"<>2016")`

[image]

Comment: *'formatted as text'* is not the same as using the `'` prefix to force text. Formatting cells as Text works while using the prefix doesn't.

Comment: Ok, it appears that the `'` prefix is being used.  Is there a way to handle that, as well as numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Text that looks like a number*" (whether in the form `'2016` or `="2016"`) can easily be turned into a "*number*" by adding 0 to it.

Try this, which should yield the correct result regardless of whether the `B3:B6` range is a number or text that looks like a number:

```
= SUMIFS(C3:C6,(B3:B6)+0,"<>2016")
```

**EDIT**

You may have to use `SUMPRODUCT` here instead, e.g.

```
= SUMPRODUCT(C3:C6,(((B3:B6)+0)<>2016)+0)
```

Comment: `Sumifs` won't handle the add operation inside the formula..  Not sure if that's a change to Excel 2016

Comment: @rvictordelta Ah, good point. In that case, you may need to use `SUMPRODUCT` instead. See my edit.

Comment: That's great, thanks.  Think I prefer the `--` notation: `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C5,--((B2:B5)+0<>2016))`

Comment: @rvictordelta That works also, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not using the `'` prefix, mentioned by Jeeped, one way to do it is:

=SUM(C3:C7)-SUMIFS(C3:C7,B3:B7,"2016",B3:B7,2016)