# Excel Sumifs using numbers stored as text in criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to use the SUMIFS() formula in excel to exclude certain rows from a table, but the criteria range includes numbers stored as text.

In the picture below I want to exclude the rows where entity id is "101000". The SUMIFS() formulas I have tried all provide the incorrect solution.

I found similar problems ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168911/handling-numbers-as-text-in-sumifs-formula) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015077/sumifs-for-filtering-on-text-value-of-numbers)). This is where I came up with the SUMPRODUCT alternative.

[image]

I am trying to see if there is an alternative using SUMIFS. The syntax of SUMPRODUCT is confusing. But more importantly it doesn't work if I have entity id's that both translate to the same number value ('0100' and '00100').

[image]

Comment: If anybody has this problem, the solutions posted worked. The approach I used was to add a character text to the front of the number text in a helper column so excel knew it was text. ="e" & B4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Office 365 you can combined the **FILTER** and **SUM** functions.

First **FILTER** the amounts

```
=FILTER(C4:C9,B4:B9<>"01000")
```

Then **SUM** the filtered amounts

```
=SUM(FILTER(C4:C9,B4:B9<>"01000"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can FILTER() accommodate more than one criteria? I'm using SUMIFS() because I have multiple criteria to filter on, this entity id is the only criteria that isn't working.

Comment: Yes.  The * is treated as an AND and the + as an OR in the include section of the FILTER function. Try this to only return the amount for 174, based on the data in the screenshot.  =SUM(FILTER($C$4:$C$9,($B$4:$B$9<>"0100")*($B$4:$B$9<>"01000")*($B$4:$B$9<>"101000")))

Comment: You saved me from repeating the same question of mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the rows whose IDs do match, and then subtract it from the total sum:

```
=SUM($C$4:$C$6)-SUMIF($B$4:$B$6,"101000",$C$4:$C$6)
```